# How to add a carriage return before every newline?

Tags: sed, grep, newlines

I have a file that only uses `\n` for new lines, but I need it to have `\r\n` for each new line. How can I do this?

For example, I solved it in Vim using `:%s/\n/\r\n/g`, but I would like to use a script or command-line application. Any suggestions?

I tried looking this up with `sed` or `grep`, but I got immediately confused by the escape sequence workarounds (I am a bit green with these commands).

If interested, the application is related to my question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596538/debugging-mercurial-patch-import-from-git-repo-hg-import-is-failing-but-the)

Comment: Do you want a `\r\n` added to the last line of the file, even if none exists? See this Vim question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263869/227738

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [unix2dos](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) (which found on Debian):

```
unix2dos file
```

Note that this implementation won't insert a `CR` before every `LF`, only before those `LF`s that are not already preceded by one (and only one) `CR` and will skip binary files (those that contain byte values in the 0x0 -> 0x1f range other than `LF`, `FF`, `TAB` or `CR`).

or use `sed`:

```
CR=$(printf '\r')
sed "s/\$/$CR/" file
```

or use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' file
```

or:

```
awk -v ORS='\r\n' 1 file
```

or use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's|\n|\r\n|' file
```

Comment: Note that [unix2dox](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) won't insert a `CR` before _every_ LF, only before those LFs that are not already preceded by one (and only one) CR.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the point, added it to my answer.

Comment: The key piece of information for me here was using `'\r'` with `sed` does the trick.

Comment: Won't your `perl` code add a `\r` to lines that may already contain that character, resulting in `\r\r\n`?

Answer (score 10):

This is exactly what [`unix2dos`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos) does:

```
$ unix2dos file.txt
```

That will replace `file.txt` in-place with a version with CRLF line endings.

If you want to do it with `sed`, you can insert a carriage return at the end of every line:

```
sed -e 's/$/\r/' file.txt
```

This replaces ([`s`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)) the zero-size area right before the end of the line ([`$`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions)) with `\r`. To do in-place replacement (like `unix2dos` does), use `sed -i.bak`, although that is a non-standard extension - if you don't have it, use a temporary file.

Comment: Use `\r` in replacement is not portable. At least, it won't work in Mac OSX.

Comment: Note that there are several implementations of unix2dos. You may want to give a link to the home page of a specific implementation (like http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html as found on Debian) instead of http://linux.die.net/man/ which doesn't make it clear which implementation (or version) is documented. Note that there are some `u2d`, `ux2dos`, `todos` commands around as well.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this with POSIX is tricky:

- [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not support `\r` or `\15`. Even if it did, the in place
  option `-i` is not POSIX
- [POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does support `\r` and `\15`, however the `-i inplace` option
  is not POSIX
- *d2u* and *dos2unix* are not [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), but *ex* is
- [POSIX ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) does not support `\r`, `\15`, `\n` or `\12`

To remove carriage returns:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

To add carriage returns:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\n","\r&");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing the conversion on a Unix machine (OS X, Linux), open the file with `vi` or `vim`:

```
$ vim my-file
```

press the ESC key to ensure that you are not in insert mode, then type

```
:set ff=dos
```

or

```
:set fileformat=dos
```

This does conversion in place by setting the file format.

To write the file and quit the editor use

```
:wq
```

On the command line you can do

```
$ vi +':w ++ff=dos' +':q' my-file
```

Comment: thanks for explaining all the steps - for a newbie it makes it much easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

In awk you can try

```
awk '{print $0 "\r"}'
```

Or

```
awk -v r=$'\r' '{print $0 r}'
```

The `$'\r'` is an example of ANSI-C style quoting as supported by a few shells like `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh` [and likely to be included in issue 8 of the Single Unix Specification](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=249).

It offers a general way to express weird characters, try this, for example:

```
awk -v r=$'\U0001F608' '{print $0 r}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A portable shell function that will do this:

```
u2dos() (set -f; IFS='
'; printf '%s\r\n' $(cat "$1"))
```

With that you can do:

```
u2dos file >dosfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ cat unix2dos.raku
my $fh1 = open $*IN, :r;

#below use :w (write-only) or :x (:x write-only :exclusive i.e. 'no-clobber')
my $fh2 = open $*OUT, :x, nl-out => "\r\n";

for $fh1.lines() { $fh2.put($_) };

$fh1.close;
$fh2.close;
```

Save the above file to a script (e.g. "unix2dos.raku"), add a shebang line and make it executable--or simply call it at the command line:

```perl
~$ raku unix2dos.raku < ends_with_LF.txt > ends_with_CRLF.txt
```

Example Input showing Unix line endings with `0a` per line:

```perl
~$ jot -w '%d' 5 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 33 0a 34 0a  35 0a                    |1.2.3.4.5.|
0000000a
```

Example Output (adds Raku script) to generate DOS line endings with `0d 0a` per line:

```perl
~$ jot -w '%d' 5 | raku unix2dos.raku | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0d 0a 32 0d 0a 33 0d  0a 34 0d 0a 35 0d 0a     |1..2..3..4..5..|
```

References:
https://docs.raku.org/language/newline.html
https://raku.org

Example Source:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742732/227738

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `sed` command:

```
 sed -i 's/$/\x0D/g' file.txt
```

- `$` - regex for end of line
- `\x0D` - hex value for carriage return in ASCII

```bsh
~] cat -v file.txt  
line1
line2
line3
line4

~] sed -i 's/$/\x0D/g' file.txt

~] cat -v file.txt             
line1^M
line2^M
line3^M
line4^M
```