# Replace LF with CRLF at the beginning of a file

Tags: sed

I am writing a script that iterates through all the files and replaces line feeds at the beginning of each file.
For a file like this,

```
\n
\n
A line \r\n
Another line \r\n
\r
\f
\n
\n
Few more lines \r\n
\r\n
```

I need to replace all line feeds at the beginning of the file with CRLF, i.e.

```
\r\n
\r\n
A line \r\n
Another line \r\n
\r
\f
\n
\n
Few more lines \r\n
\r\n
```

I tried using,

```
sed -i 's/^[\n]/\r\n/' file.txt
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: I am able to replace a range of lines with,

```
sed '1,2s/^/\r/'
```

But is there a way to identify if the first character in the file is line feed?

Comment: what is beginning of file? for applying `sed` to a range of lines, simply specify them (e.g. lines 1 to 5): `sed '1,5command' file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a carriage return before every newline?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153091/how-to-add-a-carriage-return-before-every-newline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, then you can use the special address form `0,/./` to make substitutions only in the portion of a file up to the first non-empty line. To illustrate:

```
~$ cat -e file.txt
$
$
non empty line$
non empty line$
$
$
non-empty line$
$
```

(the `$` signs indicate literal line endings: see `man cat`); then

```
~$ sed '0,/./ s/^$/\r/' file.txt | cat -e
^M$
^M$
non empty line$
non empty line$
$
$
non-empty line$
$
```

where the `^M` characters indicate the inserted CRs.