# Add a CR before every LF

Tags: bash, text-processing, newlines

I have a text file being processed on a Windows machine.  There is a need to remove trailing tab characters prior to using `bcp` utility to load the data from the file into a database table.

The following command, in a Bash script, stripped out the trailing tabs:

```bash
sed 's/[\t]*$//' < ./input/raw.txt >> ./input/data.txt
```

but it converted the `CR`-`LF` to `LF` which caused the `bcp` command to fail.

In an effort to keep the `CR`-`LF` I tried this:

```bash
sed 's/[\t]*$/$CR/' < ./input/raw.txt >> ./input/data.txt
```

but that resulted in:

[image]

The desired outcome is:

[image]

How do I modify the command to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a carriage return before every newline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153091/how-to-add-a-carriage-return-before-every-newline)

Comment: It does not.  That is the post I used to write the modification to my original code that successfully removed the trailing tabs.

Comment: The reason your script put literal `$CR` in the file is because variables are not expanded inside single quotes, only in double quotes.

Comment: You're already using `\t` in the expression, why not use ``\r` as well?

Comment: Not sure why you're `>>` appending into a different file? Wouldn't you want to create a new one?

Comment: How exactly are you running bash on this Windows machine? Is it Windows Subsystem for Linux? Git Bash for Windows? Cygwin? In my own experiments, using `$` in Git Bash for Windows will match on both LF and CRLF, while in WSL (Ubuntu distro) it will match on LF only.

Comment: @MJ713 Git Bash for Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that in standard `sed`, `sed 's/[\t]*$//'` removes all backslash and `t` characters from the end of the line. The GNU implementation of `sed` only does it when there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in its environment.

`sed 's/\t*$//'` is unspecified, but at least with GNU `sed`, that happens to remove trailing TABs whether `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or not.

Here you could do:

```
sed $'s/\t*$/\r/'
```

Using the ksh93-style `$'...'` form of quotes inside which things like `\t` or `\r` are expanded to TAB and CR respectively. That's now supported by many other shells and will be in the next version of the POSIX standard for `sh`.

If you have TAB and CR characters in shell variables, which you could do without `$'...'` for instance with:

```
eval "$(printf 'TAB="\t" CR="\r"')"
```

You could do:

```
sed "s/$TAB*\$/$CR/"
```

But that has to be within double-quotes. Inside single quotes, no expansion is performed.

Now, in the unlikely event that the input doesn't end in a LF character (which would make it invalid text in Unix), those (with GNU `sed` at least) would produce a file that ends in a CR character, making it invalid in DOS as well.

To convert the text files from Unix to DOS, you could use the `unix2dos` utility instead which wouldn't have the problem:

```
sed $'s/\t*$//' | unix2dos
```

Or use `perl`'s `sed` mode:

```
perl -pe 's/\t*$//; s/\n/\r\n/'
```

`perl -p` works like `sed` in that it runs the code for each line of input, except that in `perl` the pattern space (`$_` there) has the full line including the line delimiter. It also supports those `\t`, `\n`, `\r` escapes (while standard `sed` only supports `\n` and only in regular expressions), and can cope with non-text files.

Comment: Does the `perl` answer avoid creating erroneous line endings like `\r\r\n` ? Or do you need a final clause like `unless /\r\n/` to prevent substitution of pre-existing Windows CRLF endings?

Comment: No, but you could always do: `perl -pe 's/\t*\r?$//; s/\n/\r\n/'` or `perl -pe 's/\t*\r*$//; s/\n/\r\n/'` for that.

Comment: Thx, that makes sense!

Answer (score 25):

You need to install the `unix2dos` package.  It has two utilities:

```
unix2dos    Convert UNIX newlines to CR-LF
dos2unix    Convert DOS CR-LF to UNIX newlines
```

Let's create a test file of five lines, and do a hex dump to examine the line endings:

```
$ jot -w 'line %d' 5 > foo
$ hexdump -C foo
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 20 31 0a 6c  69 6e 65 20 32 0a 6c 69  |line 1.line 2.li|
00000010  6e 65 20 33 0a 6c 69 6e  65 20 34 0a 6c 69 6e 65  |ne 3.line 4.line|
00000020  20 35 0a                                          | 5.|
00000023
```

We see that each line ends in a newline character, hex 0a.

Now we convert those newlines to DOS CR-LF line endings, and inspect again:

```
$ unix2dos foo
$ hexdump -C foo
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 20 31 0d 0a  6c 69 6e 65 20 32 0d 0a  |line 1..line 2..|
00000010  6c 69 6e 65 20 33 0d 0a  6c 69 6e 65 20 34 0d 0a  |line 3..line 4..|
00000020  6c 69 6e 65 20 35 0d 0a                           |line 5..|
00000028
```

Now each line ends in CR-LF, hex 0d 0a.

Finally, we can convert the file back to the original UNIX newlines:

```
$ dos2unix foo
$ hexdump -C foo
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 20 31 0a 6c  69 6e 65 20 32 0a 6c 69  |line 1.line 2.li|
00000010  6e 65 20 33 0a 6c 69 6e  65 20 34 0a 6c 69 6e 65  |ne 3.line 4.line|
00000020  20 35 0a                                          | 5.|
00000023
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ cat unix2dos.raku
my $fh1 = open $*IN, :r;
#below :x opens write-only :exclusive (i.e. 'no-clobber')
my $fh2 = open $*OUT, :x, nl-out => "\r\n";

for $fh1.lines() { $fh2.put($_) };

$fh1.close;
$fh2.close;
```

Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) is a programming language in the Perl family. One thing the Perl6 project tried to do was abstract out OS-specific niggles to make code more portable, and one of these niggles is newline processing. Raku provides a `nl-in` parameter for filehandle input (defaults to `["\x0A", "\r\n"]`), autochomps lines by default, uses `\n`-terminated newlines internally, and provides a `nl-out` parameter for filehandle output (defaults to `"\n"`).

The key statement by the OP is as follows:

> ...but it converted the `CR-LF` to `LF` which caused the bcp command to fail.

So for the Raku script above (on whatever platform you happen to be working on), you can open a file for writing and set `nl-out => \r\n`, i.e. newline-out to CRLF. Raku reads `lines` lazily, so this script should be memory-efficient. Even without making the above script executable, you can call it at the command line as follows:

```perl
~$ raku unix2dos.raku < ends_with_LF.txt > ends_with_CRLF.txt
```

The above script defaults to taking `$*IN` stdin and therefore is a "one-off", but Raku provides functions for reading`$*ARGFILES` and `dir` directories as well. Finally, there's an excellent summary of newline processing in Raku at the first link below:

https://docs.raku.org/language/newline.html
https://raku.org